# yfinance: OperationalError('unable to open database file')

Tags: python, pandas, yfinance, stockquotes

I'm getting the following error when trying to download stock price data from yahoo finance using the yfinance package: OperationalError('unable to open database file')

It seems the prices are just not downloading. What can I do to resolve this error? I've not come across a solution yet on the internet.

Thank you very much in advance!

[Unable to open database file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RwepZ.png)

I googled, upgraded pip installation, reinstalled anaconda, resetted Windows, played around with folder permissions, ran as admin... nothing worked.

Comment: Seems like a bug: [`GH1694`](https://github.com/ranaroussi/yfinance/issues/1694).

Comment: yea, i'm getting the same thing

Comment: [Code, data and error tracebacks are required to be posted as text, not images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors/285557#285557)

Answer (score 7):

```bash
pip uninstall yfinance && pip install yfinance==0.2.28
```

worked for me...

Comment: Helped on python 3.10.12. Thanks! yfinance defaulted to 0.2.29 while `pip install`.

Comment: YES!! This is the way, thank you!! Your solution works like a charm and saved my life :D THANK YOU!

Comment: add some details in your answer

Answer (score 1):

If tool has no permissions to create a temporary folder to store the downloaded data, it throws this error. For example I got the same issue in Windows. Created a folder `py-yfinance` in the directory- `C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\`, fixed the issue. It should work in other os also. Reference from https://github.com/ranaroussi/yfinance/issues/1694

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it was a temporary connection error from their side. It should work now as you can see from me:[image]

Comment: [Code, data and error tracebacks are required to be posted as text, not images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors/285557#285557)